# Is there a way to get a VCL Control's name through the windows API?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have the Hwnd of a VCL Control that is located on another process' window. Is there a way to get its VCL name (`TControl.Name` property) of that control through the windows API?
I need the name because there are several TEdits on that window and I need to identify the one I want in order to send a `WM_SETTEXT` message to it.

Both applications were built with Delphi 2010.

Comment: If you control the code you can respond to a user defined window message by returning the name

Comment: Or simply define your own set of WM_USER  messages

Comment: Do you have control over the two applications? can you re-build both?

Comment: I control the first app and have some control over the other, however changing the second app would defy the purpose of doing this in the first place: interact with the second app without changing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Delphi has builtin function `FindControl()` which returns `TWinControl` of specified hWnd. But it works for the same instance of VCL. I think you should investigate it. After you have pointer to TWinControl object its name (string) located at `+8` offset. You can try ReadProcessMemory for read it. The main problem here is to create version of FindControl() suits your needs.

Edit: (Finally got it :D ) Call GetWinControlName function

```
// Get Pointer to TWinControl in another process
function GetWinControl(Wnd: HWND; out ProcessId: THandle): Pointer;
var
  WindowAtomString: String;
  WindowAtom: ATOM;
begin
  if GetWindowThreadProcessId(Wnd, ProcessId) = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;

  // This is atom for remote process (See controls.pas for details on this)
  WindowAtomString := Format('Delphi%.8X',[ProcessID]);
  WindowAtom := GlobalFindAtom(PChar(WindowAtomString));
  if WindowAtom = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;

  Result := Pointer(GetProp(Wnd, MakeIntAtom(WindowAtom)));
end;

function GetWinControlName(Wnd: HWND): string;
var
  ProcessId: THandle;
  ObjSelf: Pointer;
  Buf: Pointer;
  bytes: Cardinal;
  destProcess: THandle;
begin
  ObjSelf := GetWinControl(Wnd, ProcessId);

  destProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, TRUE, ProcessId);
  if destProcess = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;

  try
    GetMem(Buf, 256);
    try
      if not ReadProcessMemory(destProcess, Pointer(Cardinal(ObjSelf) + 8), Buf, 4, bytes) then RaiseLastOSError;
      if not ReadProcessMemory(destProcess, Pointer(Cardinal(Buf^)), Buf, 256, bytes) then RaiseLastOSError;
      Result := PChar(Buf);
    finally
      FreeMem(Buf);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(destProcess);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Now I just need to find a `FindControl` function that works in another process :/

Comment: Try to use this part of inner 'ObjectFromHWnd' function 'Result := Pointer(SendMessage(Handle, RM_GetObjectInstance, 0, 0))'. I think you should remove all of this ProcessId checks.

Comment: The offset depends on the Delphi version that was used to create the other control. TObject.InstanceSize was changed when they introduced System.TMonitor.

Comment: wouldn't the `RM_GetObjectInstance` from my process be the wrong one since Delphi register one `RM_GetObjectInstance` for every application?

Comment: Yes its different. Futher investigating this I found that you can use WindowAtom to determine pointer to control. I'll try to check this out and if I success with it, I'll edit my answer with some code ;)

Comment: "After you have pointer to TWinControl object" Er, quite. That's the crux of the question.

Comment: Finnaly done this :D. Read last edit of answer. Code is not very good, written just to check that it works, sorry.

Comment: @Samaliani it's laking a `FreeMem(Buf, 256)` and a `CloseHandle(destProcess)` but the concept works great, thanks.

Comment: No problem. As I said not pretty code, just works ) It was interesting task.

Comment: @Daniel: FYI, the `RM_GetObjectInstance` issue was finally fixed in XE3 to use the same message ID for all VCL processes, instead of unique message IDs for each process.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no Windows API function that will yield the control's name. That is a private Delphi implementation detail.

If you control the code of the target process then clearly you can implement some form of IPC to solve the problem. Otherwise, any solution that yields the control name is going to involve rather vile hacking. One approach would be to inject into the process a DLL built with the same version of the runtime. Get that DLL to find the VCL control reference from the HWND and read out the name. There are lots of variants on this and the nicely done `ReadProcessMemory` trickery offered by @Samaliani's answer is typical of the hoops you have to jump through.

However, I can think of a much simpler solution to your problem. Find the handles to all the edit controls and use those handles to receive the coordinates of the controls. The relative positions of the edit controls will be enough to identify which one is the desired target. And please read @dthorpe's comments below for some more useful thoughts.

Comment: One man's vile hack is another man's patented test automation framework.

Comment: @dthorpe Indeed so. Do you like my alternate solution though?

Comment: Comparing window rects is adequate for manual confirmation ("is this it?") but not reliable long term. Window sizes and positions can change with localization. Once the target is identified, remembering its child window index or tab order index might be a more reliable tag over time. Tab order usually doesn't change in localization.

Comment: Right on the money @dthorpe, it's a test automation framework, just not patented.

Comment: @kobik Hardly. That doesn't use the Windows API. It uses private implementation details of Delphi.

Comment: @kobik Whatever. It's down to the interpretation of the question. I imagined that Daniel was asking for a simple API call that would yield the result.

Comment: @kobik OK. Fine, thanks. I wouldn't have minded if you had left it there. You are perfectly entitled to your downvotes.

Comment: @Daniel The test automation system I implemented for VCL in the 1990's was patented by Borland.

Comment: @dthorpe So you are that guy, I knew I had heard that name before. You are a great software engineer, and I'm a fan! Your name comes up every now and then when I'm reading about Delphi and its internals.